# Typescript to corresponding C# syntax

Tags: c#, typescript, typeconverter

I have the following Type in typescript

```
export type Excludable<T extends FilterValue> = T & { isExcluded?: boolean }
```

where FilterValue:

```
export type FilterValue = {
   id: number,
   label: string,
}
```

type T could be the following:

```
export type AreaFilterValue = FilterValue & {
  type: "Area",
  taxonomy?: LocationTaxonomy,
}
```

Can I somehow write the above in C#?

ideally I would need something like:

```
 public class Excludable<T> : T where T : FilterValue
 {
        bool? IsExcluded { get; set; }

 }
```

but it shows an error of "Could not derive from T cause it's a type parameter"

What I am trying to achieve is to have an object like:

1. `{ id, label }`
2. `{ id, label, isExcluded }`
3. `{ id, label, isExcluded, type, taxonomy }`

Edit: I currently have set in C# that `FilterValue` has the `isExcluded` property

Ideally I would like to use it in my code like follows:

```
public Excludable<AreaFilterValue>[] OpenAreas { get; set; }
```

Comment: Retrun a KeyValuePair<int,string> so you do not need to create a class.  It looks like you need a method with three overrides 1) KeyValuePair<int,string> GetType(int id, string label) 2) KeyValuePair<int,string> GetType(int id, string label, bool IsExcluded) 3) KeyValuePair<int,string> GetType(int id, string label, bool IsExcluded, string taxonomy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  & { isExcluded?: boolean }
```

Is Bassicaly an anonymous Extended interface:

```
public interface FilterValueExt : FilterValue {
   bool? IsExcluded { get; set; }
}
```

You cant make generic subclasses in c# so for every use of `Excludable` You'd have to create a new interface or use `Excludable` as an interface and implement on any class that uses this method:

```
public interface Excludable
  bool? IsExcluded { get; set; }
}

pulic class AreaFilterValue : FilterValue, Excludable  {
   // implementation here +  type: "Area",   taxonomy?: LocationTaxonomy,
}
```

i'dd suggest you do the same in typescript:

```
interface Excludable{
    isExcluded?: boolean
}

var t= {isExcluded: true||false||undefined}; // typescript knows this is/canbe a excludable
```